# Automatically register payment and generate invoice when amount is zero

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When pressing the "Confirm Sale" button, even if the total amount to be paid is zero (because of the 100% discount), the Register Payment popup is getting displayed - and I need to press Cancel in the popup to proceed (generate invoice & and mark it as paid).

Can I bypass displaying the popup - automatically generate the invoice and mark it as paid?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

1. Write a module to overwrite the `button`s named `Create Invoice` method and call a method to check if the total amount is zero then prepare the invoice values and automatically generate the invoice and view if needed. The rest with non-zero amount should follow the wizard path.
2. Create an automated action, where you can filter the SOs which are confirmed and has zero total and automatically create the invoices. You can combine this with scheduled actions to check it every X minutes or hours. This can be tricker than explained and may require some coding in the action.

Comment: If i follow the first method, would it prevent displaying the Register Payment popup at the time of Confirmation?

Comment: I've updated my answer. There are `Create Invoice` buttons that call directly to the wizard named `action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv`. You need to overwrite the button to call to a method. In the same sense you can write a method that creates the invoice if total is zero if not can call the wizard again. And to simply answer your question, if you overwrite it and return the invoice view instead of the wizard view that will skip the popup.

Comment: I've ended up making a custom method `action_confirm` by combining the one under `bahmni-sale` & one under `odoo/sale` and added a condition before the code to display the popup. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.